# How can vim tell me which buffer is changed on disk among multiple buffers?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, gvim, vim-windows

I am using this code in my vimrc 
if a file is changed outside vim, it shows `File changed on disk. Buffer reloaded.`

```
set autoread
autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI * if mode() != 'c' | checktime | endif
autocmd FileChangedShellPost *
  \ echohl WarningMsg | echo "File changed on disk. Buffer reloaded." | echohl None
```

but i am facing a problem. 
When i open multiple files via `:tabnew filename` in vim and let's say among 4 files, **one file** has been changed 
vim doesn't specify me which one (is changed)

Now can anyone give me a fix? 
any string or something through which vim will say, `A.cpp file changed on disk. Buffer reloaded.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that is associated with the currently executing autocommand can be retrieved with this function call:

```
expand('<afile>')
```

Somewhat contrived but easy to understand test...

```
augroup AfileTest
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePost * echom "I saved file " . expand('<afile>')
augroup END
```

After loading this and running `:w` the message with the affected file will be displayed.

Here's one possibility for your use case:

```
autocmd FileChangedShellPost *
  \ echohl WarningMsg | echo "File " . expand('<afile>') . " changed on disk. Buffer reloaded." | echohl None
```

See [`:h <afile>`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Cafile%3E)

Comment: Awesome it works.. but how about if multiple files change? if i had three tabs and among those, two are changed, how can i make vim to show "file A.cpp B.cpp changed" ?

Comment: You can't. At least not without writing a bunch of extra code. Each file related autocommand event is associated with a single file. You'd have to store the filenames somewhere and then print them all at once after the fact. Non-trivial. If you really want to do it then go ahead and ask a new question since that's a totally separate thing.

Comment: One big issue is determining/specifying that multiple events should be folded into a single message or if they happened far apart enough that they should be printed individually. Maybe a timer that periodically checks the "cache" of filenames and prints whatever's there then clears it for the next "round".

Comment: no, just for the opened tabs inside vim.. i don't need the others

Comment: range is minimum 4 files, maximum 6 files

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the file modification(s) are taking place outside of Vim so the timing is an issue.

Comment: the code specifies, if vim buffer is gained focus, or mouse hold, then it will automatically execute

Comment: I think you're not understanding what I'm trying to say. Regardless, you should definitely ask a new question if you want to pursue this. Cheers.

Comment: here it is https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/31837/36876

Comment: Cool. I'll take a look when I get a chance.

Comment: much appreciated