# how can i define g:errorMessageString as a List?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, gvim

related to this thread [Multiple error messages in vim message history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18981784/15770124)

How can i define `g:errorMessageString` as a List? 
Can anyone help me fix this?

i am using this code in my vimrc 
but i don't know why the errors don't show as a list

```
set autoread
autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI * if mode() != 'c' | checktime | endif
autocmd FileChangedShellPost *
  \ echohl WarningMsg | echom "File " . expand('<afile>') . " changed on disk. Buffer reloaded." | echohl None

function! LocalError(err)
    " Update the errorMessageString
    let g:errorMessageString = a:err
    execute 'autocmd VimEnter * echohl ErrorMsg | echomsg' string(g:errorMessageString) '| echohl None'
endfunction
```

I hate to manually type `:messages` to see All those messages

Comment: `let g:errorMessageString=[]` see `:h list`

Comment: can you refactor my code.. why it isn't showing all errors as a list?

Comment: I have no idea what problem you are actually trying to solve

Comment: related to this thread https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/31837/36876